# Gettext in PHP not working anymore after server upgrade 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: server, upgrade, php, locale, gettext

as in subject, after upgrading Ubuntu Server from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS my PHP websites no longer adapt to browser locale as it used to work before the upgrade.

My wanted locale files (`it_IT.UTF-8`) are still there, I still bind them with:

```
bindtextdomain('messages', $locale_folder);
bind_textdomain_codeset('messages', 'UTF-8');
```

locale is available in `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED` and to be on the safe side I run `sudo locale-gen it_IT.UTF-8` anyway and restarted apache with `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Still no luck.

Any help to track this down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this fixed it:

```
putenv("LANGUAGE=it_IT.UTF-8");
```

This is the result of a full trial and error day, no comment...

Comment: Thank you so much for this - I've just spent more time than I have trying to get godforsaken gettext working... time to switch to something else I think